# Delete CSV File from FTP server in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, delete-file, azure-data-factory

I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

I'm trying to use the delete activity to remove the CSV file I just processed in a pipeline.

After setting up the delete activity, I see nothing that indicates that it'll delete the file from my FTP server. After I debug/run the pipeline, I get an error. Everything I've seen related to using this activity is in regard to some other storage type.

Here's the actual error:

```
{
    "errorCode": "3703",
    "message": "Invalid delete activity payload with 'folderPath' that is required and cannot be empty.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "DeleteCSVFromFTPServer"
}
```

But there's nowhere on the activity to specify the folder path.

[image]
[image]

Can anyone point me to and FTP specific example of how to use the delete activity?

Answer (score 1):

I figured I'd answer my own question since I figured this out about 5 minutes after I posted the question.

Hopefully this will help someone else out down the road.

The issue was that in the Dataset I had not supplied a value for the folder path. Leaving it empty worked on import, but would not work for the delete.

I supplied a `.` in the dataset's `file path` field as shown below.
[image]

Now the pipeline will run completely as I expect.